# Get image from SQLServer to Android using JDBC

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to get an image from sql server and use it in my android application. The code for creating table and storing the image in the database table is :

```
create table Imagee (ID int not null,Img VARBINARY(max) not null)

insert into Imagee (ID, Img) 
SELECT 1, BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Razvan\PozeDB\hawai.png', Single_Blob) as iamge
```

The code I am currently trying to use, but it does not work and i don't get any errors is :

```
String query = "select * from Imagee ";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

if (rs.next()) {

    final String imagine;
    imagine = rs.getString("Img");

    byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(imagine, Base64.DEFAULT);
    final Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //Here "img" is the ImageView
                img.setImageBitmap(decodebitmap);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Eceptie",e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

This code is surrounded by try catch statements and in the "doInBackground()" method. The connection to the server is properly made. I can get the Id, but not the Image.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: why not `String query = "select Img from Imagee ";`

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve a string from the Img field? Shouldn't there be a method that returns a bit-stream like getBytes or something? Also, you really shouldn't be storing binary data on a database, you are better off storing just the URI and storing the file somewhere on the filesystem, then retrieving it via http.